# how to merge df's together with duplicate keys in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following 2 data frames that are taken from excel files:

df1 = 10000 rows (like the master list that has all unique #s)

df2 = 670 rows

I am loading a excel file (df2) that has zip, address, state and I want to match that info and then add on the supplier # from df1 so that I could have 1 file thats still 670 rows but now has the supplier row column.

Since there was no unique key  between two dataframes, I thought that I could make a unique key to merge on by joining 3 columns together - zip, address, and state and join them with a "-".. maybe this is too risky for a match? df1 has a ton of duplicate addresses, zips, states so I couldnt do something like joining just zip and state.

```
df1 =
(10000 rows)
  (unique)
 supplier_num  ZIP   ADDRESS        STATE   CCCjoin
0  7100000  35481  14th street     CA      35481-14th street-CA
1  7000005  45481  14th street     CA      45481-14th street-CA
2  7000006  45482  140th circle     CT     45482-140th circle-CT
3  7000007  35482  140th circle     CT     35482-140th circle-CT
4  7000008  35483  13th road        VT     35483-13th road-VT
...

df2 = 
(670 rows) 
    ZIP   ADDRESS          STATE         CCCjoin
0    35481  14th street     CA      35481-14th street-CA
1    45481  14th street     CA      45481-14th street-CA
2   45482  140th circle     CT     45482-140th circle-CT
3    35482  140th circle     CT     35482-140th circle-CT
4    35483  13th road        VT     35483-13th road-VT
...

OUTPUT:
 df3 =
(670 rows)
    ZIP   ADDRESS          STATE         Unique Key          (Unique)supplier_num
0    35481  14th street     CA      35481-14th street-CA          7100000 
1    45481  14th street     CA      45481-14th street-CA          7100005
2   45482  140th circle     CT     45482-140th circle-CT          7100006
3    35482  140th circle     CT     35482-140th circle-CT          7100007
4    35483  13th road        VT     35483-13th road-VT            7100008
...
670    15483  13 baker  road        CA     15483-13 baker road-CA            7100009
```

I've looked around on here and found some helpful tricks and I think ive made some progress. Here is some code that I tried.

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('CCCjoin').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('CCCjoin').cumcount()

then I merge:

merged_table = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['CCCjoin', 'g'], how='inner').drop('g', axis =1 )
```

This *sort of* works. I get a match of 293 rows and I cross checked the supplier number and it matches the address.

What am I missing to get the 377 matches?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: White space problems in CCCjoin?

Comment: The first way to check what's missing is to compare the contents of df1['g'] and df2['g']. Try merging these two columns and reordering them.

Comment: df1 has already all data df2 has. why do you need to merge them?  btw you don't need a new column. you can join with multiple columns df3= pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on=['supplier_num','ZIP','ADDRESS'] , right_on = 
['supplier_num','ZIP','ADDRESS']  )